# OpenCV SVM Train

Tags: opencv, svm

I am using SVM.train command (with appropriate parameters defined) with openCv. Next, instead of using svm.predict, I want to use my algorithm for classification purpose. 
Is it possible? Can I access support vectors generated while training? If so, how ?

Comment: "I want to use my algorithm" - what is this ? yes, you can query the support vectors *after* training.

Comment: How can I use Support vectors generated after the training phase? I mean how can I query them?

Comment: [rtfm](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d1/d2d/classcv_1_1ml_1_1SVM.html#a2c3fb4b3c80b8fce0b8654f103339300) ?

Comment: If you could give an example here ??

Comment: Also if you could suggest Algorithms for prediction (Sample data to be classified) , given that we have Support Vectors generated from training stage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. 
Usually you save your Support Vectors after training in an XML file. 
Which looks like this:

```
clasificador = new CvSVM(trainingData, classes, new Mat(), new Mat(),
                params);
clasificador.save(XML);
```

Now you can define your own classificador. I guess you already did it. Then its up on you to write a method which should look like this

```
clasificador.load( new File( XML ).getAbsolutePath() );
```